# String replace only first character in Laravel View

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel for my website.

In my view, I received a string variable from controller like this "01230456", I want to replace only first character "0" to "ABC", not the second "0" in string.

I tried `preg_replace('\0\', 'ABC', $string, 1)`, but it  replaced all "0" character in my string.

How should I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
preg_replace('/0/', 'ABC', $string, 1)
```

or you can use substr

```
$sub = substr($string, 1);
$new = 'ABC' . $sub;
```

Comment: preg_replace('/0/', 'ABC', $string, 1) is worked for me, thank you very much!